# Xamarin.Forms Dependency Service ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin.Forms Dependency Service to make a phone call in my PCL.

The method itself is :

```
 public void Call(string number)
        {
                var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(number);
                var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, uri);
                Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent);
        }
```

Method call:

```
        DependencyService.Get<IPhoneDialler>().Call("+447836726414");
```

Using it throws

```
Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent
```

Same approach works completely fine when used on another service (Geolocation via Xamarin.Mobile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Suggestion 2:**

Adjust your call method to use Intent.ACTION_DIAL

```
public void Call(String number){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+number));
    Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent)
}
```

[1] http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

**Suggestion 1:**

Have you got the [assembly] attribute above the class (and outside any namespaces that have been defined)

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency (typeof (IPhoneDialler))]
```

Comment: Yep, everything is there

Comment: Updated my answer, please see above, try Suggestion 2, using Intent.ACTION_DIAL

Comment: In suggestion 2#, I made method private by mistake. Updated to public.

Comment: Thanks, using a different intent seems to have fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm resurrecting a dead thread, but I spent almost 2 days trying to solve this problem.

This thread showed up on almost every search I did, so I figure putting it here is reasonable.

Don't forget to wrap your Intent's in a chooser.

ex:

```
        Forms.Context.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(email, "Send Email"));
```